# strncpy making weird output

Tags: c, string, algorithm, strncpy

I'm trying to make an algorithm for `strncpy`
I read how it work in the manual and made my algorithm
then I made a test to see if there's any difference between my `ft_strncpy` and the real `strncpy`

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char    *ft_strncpy(char *dest, char *src, unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int    i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < n && src[i] != '\0')
    {
        dest[i] = src[i];
        i++;
    }
    while (i < n)
    {
        dest[i] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
    return (dest);
}

int main(void)
{
    char src1[] = "123456789q00000";
    char dest1[] = "zzz";
    printf("my output\n");
    printf("src1: %s\n", src1);
    ft_strncpy(dest1, src1, 8);
    printf("dest1: %s\n", dest1);

    printf("\nhow it should be\n");
    char src2[] = "123456789q00000";
    char dest2[] = "zzz";
    printf("src2: %s\n", src2);
    strncpy(dest2, src2, 8);
    printf("dest2: %s\n", dest2);
}
```

the `how it should be` section supposed to be the right output of the real `strncpy`
but I'm having weird outputs just like in the code I provided
I get this error

```c
*** buffer overflow detected ***: terminated
signal: aborted (core dumped)
```

what I understood from the manual is 
`strncpy` copies `n` first characters from `*src` to `*dest` 
so a code like

```c
    char src2[] = "123456789q00000";
    char dest2[] = "zzz";
    printf("src2: %s\n", src2);
    strncpy(dest2, src2, 10);
    printf("dest2: %s\n", dest2);
```

should output : `123456789q` as the value of `dest`
I'm I missing smth here?

Comment: [The "real" `strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) have a corner-case where it might not add the terminating null character.

Comment: But the above doesn't matter as your example code have *undefined behavior*! Your arrays `dest1` and `dest2` have enough space for the string `"zzz"` (including null terminator) but no more (i.e. it will have four elements). By using it as a destination for a longer string you go out of bounds and have the mentioned undefined behavior.

Comment: C does not have a string class so you need to handle all allocation manually. This is why I recommend to study arrays, then pointers, then strings, in that order.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so the size of `dest` has to allways be >= size of `src`?

Comment: Yes. As any beginners book, tutorial or class should have taught you: C doesn't have dynamic arrays.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think I got it so how can set this question as closed or idk should I Just leave it?

Comment: Write `strncpy(dest, src, sizeof(dest))` and make sure `dest` is an array (not a pointer). If you think you need something else, think again. Then bear in mind that you **cannot** printf  `dest` as is because **it is not a string** (it may or may not have the terminated null character). Add `dest[sizeof(dest)-1] = '\0';` if you want to make it a string.

Comment: You can write your own answer and mark it as accepted. It is the best way to close questions when you learn the answer before it is actually answered by someone else, because you have to think about the answer before writing it down.

Comment: If the size of `dest` >= size of `src` (including the null terminator) then you don't need `strncpy`. `strcpy` works better in this case. You only need `strncpy` when you may have to *truncate* the source (and then you need to write your own null terminator).

Comment: Unrelated, props to your understanding and implementation of at least the `strncpy` algorithm. You'd be amazed how many seasoned C programmers do not know that function pads the destination array with zeroes in the case where the source string is shorter than `n`.  It is fairly well known it does not terminate if the source meets/exceeds the target size, but the pad with zeros action is surprisingly elusive. `strncpy` *always* writes `n` slots; no more, no less.

Comment: For details regarding why `strncpy` is dangerous, see [Is strcpy dangerous and what should be used instead?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/281518)

Comment: The 3rd argument to strncpy must never be greater than the size of dest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in c are **not** dynamic so
I can't just initialize it with a string then try changing it to a bigger one
that will lead to an undefined behavior

besides there's a corner-case where it might not add the terminating null character so I won't be able to print it with `printf` because it's not a string anymore, it's an array.

conclusion: **Be more cautious when modifying strings.**
(answer by the help of [@Someprogrammerdude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) and [@n. 1.8e9-where's-my share m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m).)

Answer (score 0):

`strncpy(dest2, src2, 10);` has undefined behavior because it will modify 10 bytes starting with `dest2[0]`, yet `dest2` is only 4 bytes long.

You have the same problem in `ft_strncpy(dest1, src1, 8);` for the same reason.

Nothing can be concluded from tests with code that has undefined behavior. The code must be corrected first.

You code for `ft_strncpy()` seems correct, except for the type `unsigned int` for the length argument which should be `size_t`. Using `unsigned int` is probably a requirement for your school project, but a debatable one, among other counter-productive requirements such as banning `for` loops and mandating parentheses around the `return` value.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char    *ft_strncpy(char *dest, char *src, unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int    i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < n && src[i] != '\0')
    {
        dest[i] = src[i];
        i++;
    }
    while (i < n)
    {
        dest[i] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
    return (dest);
}

void dump(const char *prefix, const char *p, size_t size)
{
    size_t i;

    printf("%s: %s  [", prefix, p);
    i = 0;
    while (i < size) {
        printf(" %.2X", (unsigned char)p[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf(" ]\n");
}
    
int main(void)
{
    char src1[] = "zzz";
    char dest1[] = "123456789q00000";

    printf("my output\n");
    printf("src1: %s\n", src1);
    ft_strncpy(dest1, src1, 8);
    dump("dest1: ", dest1, sizeof dest1);

    printf("\nhow it should be\n");
    char src2[] = "zzz";
    char dest2[] = "123456789q00000";
    printf("src2: %s\n", src2);
    strncpy(dest2, src2, 8);
    dump("dest1: ", dest1, sizeof dest1);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
my output
src1: zzz
dest1: : zzz  [ 7A 7A 7A 00 00 00 00 00 39 71 30 30 30 30 30 00 ]

how it should be
src2: zzz
dest1: : zzz  [ 7A 7A 7A 00 00 00 00 00 39 71 30 30 30 30 30 00 ]
```